# TeamCity ZIP Release files

Tags: c#, continuous-integration, teamcity

I have been struggling to find a way to zip the output of a TeamCity MSBuild output so that when the build is successful compress the files in the bin\Release folder and copy them in a custom location.
Has anyone done this before?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

In order to create a new zip, inside the Artefazct Rule, just specify the path you want like : `bin/release => BuildResult.zip`

Comment: If I use this     bin/release => C:\Temp\BuildResult.zip I get the following error: Failed to upload artifact, due to error: java.io.IOException: Failed to create directory: "C:\ProgramData\JetBrains\TeamCity\system\artifacts\Common\Master Check In Build\336\C:\Temp"

Comment: That is because you specified an absolute path inside `BuildResult` where the user whicj run TeamCity does not have any access right. You add to specify a relative path, so the rule would be `<PathInYouBuild> => <OutputPath>/BuildResult.zip` You don't need to specify a local folder, TeamCity will handle it.

Comment: I was looking for a way to move the artifacts onto a different Network Machine. I managed to do that by using the SMB Upload that the teamcity has instead.